# Powershell regex are too annoying

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following URLs

```
http://servername:12345/sites/MYSITE1/SUBSITE1
http://servername:543/sites/MYSITE2/SUBSITE1/SUBSITE2
```

I would like to delete everything before and including `/sites/` to give the following output

```
MYSITE1\SUBSITE1
MYSITE2\SUBSITE1\SUBSITE2
```

I have tried `-replace "*/sites/",""` but his doesn't give me the required result.

Comment: What do mean by "I guess"? Have you tried?

Comment: Before you comment, i tried, before I posted, no.

Comment: This has been discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/give-me-teh-regez-questions)

Comment: Look, it’s great that the close-happy group is going through the Meta question. But this question has provided example input, expected output, and what Nico tried. (Maybe not until after the comment, but that was yesterday.) The right answer involved adding two whole characters. Come on.

Comment: "Powershell regex are too annoying"
This has nothing to do with PowerShell, '*' is a special character for regex in all languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` means any number of character. So it will remove all letters before the `sites`.  Some characters  `". ^ $ * + ? { [ ] \ | ( ) “` has special meaning in regex.  So we need to mask it to use literally using “\”.  Example “/” for the “/”. Try this.

```
"http://servername:12345/sites/MYSITE1/SUBSITE1" -replace ".*sites\/",""
```

Comment: That is just perfect ! Love you @Vinoth :) Thanks, really !

Comment: You could explain *how* your regex works and why the original doesn't. Thus the OP might more than just a copy-and-paste approach.